# Using the HAVING clause to identify groups with a defined combination of records

Tags: sql-server, having

I have a table with names, types and values.

```
DECLARE @t_Table TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    [Type] VARCHAR(10),
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Jill', 'Yellow', 100)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Jill', 'Blue', 200)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Jill', 'Green', 300)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Jill', 'Green', 400)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Jill', 'Green', 500)

INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Bob', 'Yellow', 100)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Bob', 'Blue', 200)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Bob', 'Green', 300)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Bob', 'Orange', 400)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Bob', 'Orange', 400)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Bob', 'Purple', 500)

INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Steve', 'Yellow', 100)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Steve', 'Blue', 200)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Steve', 'Green', 300)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Steve', 'Orange', 400)
INSERT INTO @t_Table
VALUES('Steve', 'Orange', 400)
```

I want to get the total value for groups of names where the underlying records in the group satisfy a constraint on the occurrence of specific types.  **I want to accomplish this with a single aggregate in the HAVING clause.**

In the case where I want a group with exactly one record of type *x*, exactly one record of type *y*, zero or more records of type *z* and no other records, I've arrived at the following solution, for example, when I want exactly one Yellow, one Blue and zero or more Green:

```
SELECT Name,
    TotalValue = SUM(Value)
FROM @t_Table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Yellow' THEN 1
        WHEN [Type] = 'Blue' THEN 2
        WHEN [Type] = 'Green' THEN 0
        ELSE 4 END) = 3
```

Which correctly returns this result:

```
Name       TotalValue
---------- -----------
Jill       1500
```

How would I go about constructing the following?

```
SELECT Name,
    TotalValue = SUM(Value)
FROM @t_Table
GROUP BY Name
/*HAVING exactly one record with [Type] = 'Yellow'
    and exactly one record with [Type] = 'Blue'
    and exactly one record with [Type] = 'Green'
    and zero or more records with [Type] = 'Orange'
    and no records of any other type
*/
```

Where the expected result given the data above would be

```
Name       TotalValue
---------- -----------
Steve      1400
```

I know of the following solution (below), but I need one that has a single aggregate in the `HAVING` clause. I am also open to another query structure that solves my problem as long as it is as simple or simpler as the structure I have proposed and performs similarly or better.

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    TotalValue = SUM(Value)
FROM 
    @t_Table
GROUP BY 
    Name
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] IN ('Yellow','Blue','Green','Orange') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Just syntactic sugar `IIF` but make it shorter `SELECT Name,
    TotalValue = SUM(Value)
FROM @t_Table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(IIF([Type] = 'Yellow', 1 , NULL)) = 1
    AND SUM(IIF([Type] = 'Blue',1, NULL)) = 1
    AND SUM(IIF([Type] = 'Green',1, NULL)) = 1
    AND SUM(IIF([Type] IN ('Yellow','Blue','Green','Orange'),0,1)) = 0`

Comment: Should be noted that IIF only applies to SQL Server 2014 and later.

Comment: @rwking Should be noted that **IIF applies to SQL Server 2012+.**

Comment: @lad2025 My mistake - you are correct. :)

Comment: @joe Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @rwking I wish...that would mean someone for sure has a good answer for it

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I realized even my first example of "exactly one Yellow, one Blue and zero or more Green" isn't always going to be correct.  For example, the data might contain three "Yellow" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

How about using your concept but with decimal weight on every type:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2643/0)**

```
SELECT Name,
    TotalValue = SUM(Value)
FROM @t_Table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(
  CASE [Type]
   WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 1
   WHEN 'Blue'   THEN 10
   WHEN 'Green'  THEN 100
   WHEN 'Orange' THEN 0
   ELSE 0
  END) = 111
```

It means that exactly 1-Yellow, 1-Blue, 1-Green.

More complex conditions could be accomplished by using `BETWEEN` or `< <= > =`. One note this will work as long you will search for max 9 in one group.

If you afraid of overflow due to 10 based system, consider using for example 1000 based system like:

```
SELECT Name,
    TotalValue = SUM(Value)
FROM @t_Table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(
  CASE [Type]
   WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 1.0
   WHEN 'Blue'   THEN 1000.0
   WHEN 'Green'  THEN 1000000.0
   WHEN 'Orange' THEN 0
   ELSE 0
  END) = 1 * 1000000.0 + 1 * 1000.0 + 1.0  -- For clearance use calculated version
```

Comment: This occurred to me as a solution, but if for example 11 "Yellows", 1 "Green" and some arbitrary number of "Oranges" are in a group the result will be incorrectly chosen.  Perhaps their is a similar but alternative approach that uses bit strings or bit masking?  I'm not sure how to construct it though...

Comment: So change weight only like `1, 100, 10000, 1000000` I doubt you will need to find 101 yellow or you will get INT overflow. 100 based system.

Comment: @Joe See my updated version, with 1000 based system you are almost sure, if still afraid change to 10_000 based and use decimal instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine in the HAVING clause you can compare two polynomials.
Then imagine you define (from the data you have) this polynomial:

count_YELLOW * x^3 + 
count_BLUE * x^2 + 
count_GREEN * x^1 + 
count_ORANGE

/*
    HAVING exactly one record with [Type] = 'Yellow'
    and exactly one record with [Type] = 'Blue'
    and exactly one record with [Type] = 'Green'
    and zero or more records with [Type] = 'Orange'
    and no records of any other type
*/

Now ... to express what you want in the HAVING clause you would say:

```
HAVING 
count_YELLOW * x^3 + 
count_BLUE * x^2 + 
count_GREEN * x^1 + 
count_ORANGE >=   
1 * x^3 + 
1 * x^2 + 
1 * x^1 + 
0

AND

count_YELLOW * x^3 + 
count_BLUE * x^2 + 
count_GREEN * x^1 + 
count_ORANGE <   
1 * x^4
```

Now ... 
just pick `x = sum (all counts) + 1`, 
or `x = max (all counts) + 1`, 
and you can turn this into numbers.

I think this will work. I may try it tomorrow in T-SQL.
You will run into kind of big numbers though. This is unavoidable,
since you want to encode unabmiguously a vector of 4 numbers into a single number.

Comment: I think this can be made even simpler.  Define x as you mention:

`DECLARE @l_x BIGINT
SELECT @l_x = MAX([count]) + 1
FROM (SELECT [count] = COUNT(*)
    FROM @t_Table
    GROUP BY Name, [Type]) t`

Then a having clause like this should suffice I think:

 `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Yellow' THEN POWER(@l_x, 3)
 WHEN [Type] = 'Blue' THEN POWER(@l_x, 2)
 WHEN [Type] = 'Green' THEN POWER(@l_x, 1)
 WHEN [Type] = 'Orange' THEN 0
 ELSE POWER(@l_x, 4) END) = POWER(@l_x, 3) + POWER(@l_x, 2) + POWER(@l_x, 1)`

Comment: Here is a [SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4011/0) of the above solution.

Comment: @Joe Well, OK, glad that you grasped the main idea (with the polynomial i.e. with the base-x number representation). How exactly you implement the HAVING clause, you would know that best.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is more efficient

```
with cte as 
(
select name, [type] tp, nb = count(*)
from @t_table
group by name, [type]
)

Select t1.name, sum(t1.Value)
from @ t_table t1 inner join cte t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where nb = (case t2.tp when 'Yellow' then 1
                       when 'Blue' then 1
                       ...
            end)
      AND Exist (select * from cte where name = t2.name and t2.tp = 'Yellow')
      AND Exist (select * from cte where name = t2.name and t2.tp = 'Blue')
      ...
group by t1.name
```